# Reverse proxy for a subdirectory in nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, directory

I want to set up a Reverse proxy on my VPS for my Heroku app (http://lovemaple.heroku.com)
So if I visit `mysite.com/blog` I can get the content in http://lovemaple.heroku.com

I followed the instructions on the [Apache wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Nginx_As_a_Reverse_Proxy).

```
    location /couchdb {
        rewrite /couchdb/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5984;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

I changed it to fit my situation:

```
    location /blog {
        rewrite /blog/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://lovemaple.heroku.com;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

When I visit `mysite.com/blog`, the page show up, but js/css file cannot be gotten (404).
Their link becomes `mysite.com/style.css` but not `mysite.com/blog/style.css`.

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/376162/how-can-i-create-a-location-in-nginx-that-works-with-and-without-a-trailing-slas

Answer (score 5):

You need to fix the references in your HTML, nginx isn't responsible for doing it for you.  You can set them to be agnostic to what directory they reside in:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

(instead of `"/style.css"`)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your wordpress's database, and update `siteurl` in `wp_options` to `http://lovemaple.heroku.com` is OK.