# using trailing slashes in nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, proxy

```
    location /product {
        proxy_pass http://10.0.0.25:8080;
    }
```

if I use my first location description for product folder, I should use `http://mysdomain.com/product/` and I can not use  `http://mysdomain.com/product` from browser. I mean I should use a slash end of url. I want to access product folder with two stuation.

is there s difference between this:

```
    location /product/ {
        proxy_pass http://10.0.0.25:8080;
    }
```

Answer (score 22):

These locations are different. First one will match `/production` for example, that might be not what you expected. So I prefer to use locations with a trailing slash.

Also, note that:

> If a [location](http://nginx.org/r/location) is defined by a prefix string that ends with the slash character, and requests are processed by one of proxy_pass, fastcgi_pass, uwsgi_pass, scgi_pass, or memcached_pass, then in response to a request with URI equal to this string, but without the trailing slash, a permanent redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested URI with the slash appended.

If you have something like:

```
location /product/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

and go to `http://example.com/product`, nginx will automatically redirect you to `http://example.com/product/`.

Even if you don't use one of these directives above, you could always do the redirect manually:

```
location = /product {
    rewrite ^ /product/ permanent;
}
```

or, if you don't want redirect you could use:

```
location = /product {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

Comment: I am using proxy_pass http://myip:8080/product , then call browser this address. Browser redirects me to http://myip/product and gives error page can not view.

Comment: Use backticks for code. Markdown parsed you comment and it's hard to find out what your code really is.

Comment: Thanks, it was important to know that if /product/ is added then even the browser send it /product is bound to receive the 301 from the server.
Quite valid point indeed.

Comment: @barteloma - same for me. `ip:port/path` redirects to `ip/path/`. The `:port` is lost.

Comment: @olfek did you change [`port_in_redirect`](https://nginx.org/r/port_in_redirect) directive?

Comment: @AlexeyTen nope

Comment: @olfek post new question and show there full nginx config

Answer (score 7):

No, these are not the same--you will need to use a trailing slash with a regex to match both, i.e.

```
location ~ /product/?
```

See [this related answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/376162/how-can-i-create-a-location-in-nginx-that-works-with-and-without-a-trailing-slas) for a more detailed response on how to match the entire URL.