# Nginx location directives, what is effect of slashes? "/"?

Tags: nginx, configuration

I.e., what is the difference between

```
location somefolder {

}
```

and

```
location somefolder/ {

}
```

and

```
location /somefolder {

}
```

and

```
location /somefolder/ {

}
```

I know it's kind of a silly question but honestly sometimes I get myself confused, a concise answer would be nice!

Comment: trailing slash definitely makes a difference, see http://serverfault.com/a/607731/61607 for details

Comment: First two never match, because every uri begins with slash

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/q/607615/126699